# How to regroup documentation by filename with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I'm currently writing some documentation on a big project and I am using JSDoc.

For now, I have several modules that correspond to the several micro-services of my application, I regroup the documentation with a `@module my_service` tag for each of the services.

I'm looking for a way to class the different functions of `my_service` by file, for example :

`function1` is in `index.js`
`function2` is in `database.js`

Inside the documentation created by JSDoc, is it possible to have the documentation of the `function1` in `my_service/index.js` and the documentation of the `function2` in `my_service/database.js` ?

What is the correct JSDoc tag to use ?